# Why is my dynamic data loading and refresh not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to use jQuery load to load external data on my page and then let jQuery Mobile run over it again to apply themes etc with a trigger. The data is loaded fine, but it is not reskinned properly. I just put a small example together to demonstrate this, as my entire project is too big.

I have a.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
      <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

      <script>    
function replaceData1() {
$("#a-page").load("b.html");
$("#a-page").trigger('create');
}    
    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="a-page">
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">Header A</div><!-- /header -->

            <div data-role="content" id="a-content">
            Content A
            <button onClick="replaceData1()">goto B</button>
            </div><!-- /content -->

            <div data-role="footer">Footer A</div><!-- /footer -->

            </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

And I have b.html:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="d">Header B</div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content" id="b-content">Content B</div><!-- /content -->

        <div data-role="footer">Footer B</div><!-- /footer -->
```

b.html is not a complete html file, just the content. I am not sure if this causes this issue or not.

Nevertheless, when I load a.html and click on the button, the contents from b.html is correctly loaded but not themed properly. Even if I execute trigger('create') later, it does not work. What did I do wrong? Can somebody please rewrite this, so that it works the way I intended it?

Comment: [please also take a look how stackoverflow works](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask): in case the question is answered, mark the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer to mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="a-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">Header A</div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="a-content">Content A <button onClick="$.mobile.changePage('#b-page');">goto B</button></div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">Footer A</div><!-- /footer -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <div data-role="page" id="b-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">Header B</div><!-- /header -->
    <div data-role="content" id="b-content">Content B <button onClick="$.mobile.changePage('#a-page');">goto A</button></div><!-- /content -->
    <div data-role="footer">Footer B</div><!-- /footer -->
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]